# Replace £0.00 products with POA, not working on at collection level

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I've tried multiple variations but keep failing with the following code:

This code works fine in multiple locations on my site.

```
{% if product.price == 0.00 %}
    <strong>P.O.A - Find Out More</strong> 
{% else %}
```

But I can't get it working on this code block in product-price.liquid: I've tried multiple ways of implementing it but it won't fire. I always end up seeing £0.00

```
<div class="product-price {% if compare_at_price > price %}price--on-sale{% endif %}" data-price>
            {% if compare_at_price > price %}
            <span class="price-item-medium"><b>Standard Price:</b></span>
                  <span class="price-item price-item--regular money" data-product-id="{{ product.id }}"  data-regular-price>
                      {{ compare_at_price | money }}
                  </span><be>
                  <span class="price-item"><b>Price With Discount:</b></span><span class="price-item price-item--sale" data-sale-price>
                     <span class="money" data-product-id="{{ variant.id }}">{{ price | money }}</span>
                  </span>     
            {% else %}
            <span class="price-item price-item--regular" data-regular-price>
            <span class="money" data-variant-id="{{ variant.id }}">{{ price | money }}</span>
                </span>
            <span class="price-item price-item--sale" data-sale-price></span>
</div>
    {% endif %}
    {% else %}  
          <div class="form-message form-message--error">
            <strong>Prices are restricted</strong> <a href="/account/login">Login</a>, or <a href="/account/register">Register for an account</a>.
          </div>
```

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see your condition implemented in `product-price.liquid`. Please add the code of the whole snippet including the condition that doesn't work.

Comment: here is a link to view the complete ***product-price.liquid***
[https://share.getcloudapp.com/6quByLq5]

Comment: or [https://www.codepile.net/pile/E6lmGErq]

Comment: Your links do not contain any code